# MATLAB - How do I find another column's values with the indices from a previous operation?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am currently trying to make a small matrix with Absorption Line Positions and the top N strongest Line Strengths out of a 273614x25 matrix. However, I only need the corresponding values within the range of 2045-2155 of the Wavenumber, which is column in the matrix.

Getting the indices and range down worked perfectly so far. But I tried making a small for-loop which takes these indices and range from column 1 and tries to assign the indices of the top N highest values.

I just need a Nx2 matrix with column 1 having the Wave Numbers and column two having the top N Line strengths with their corresponding wavenumber.

So far I've got this:

```
A = readmatrix("linelist_H216O.txt");
RangeMin = 2045;
RangeMax = 2155;
MinInd = find(A(:,1)>RangeMin,1);
MaxInd = find(A(:,1)>=RangeMax,1);
B = A(RangeMin:RangeMax,5);
L = maxk(B, 20, 1);
IND = zeros(length(L),1);

for i = 1:length(L)  
    IND(i) = find(A(MinInd:MaxInd,5)==L(i,:),1);
end 

TopLines = [IND+MinInd, L];
```

But the problem is in line 11, where it says that both sides have a different number of elements.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I can't seem to upload the text file, I'm not sure if that is necessary though.

Comment: Presumably `MaxInd = find(A(:,1)>=RangeMax,1);` should use `<=` instead if you want `RangeMax` to be an upper limit? You can just do something like `idx = (A(:,1)>RangeMin) & (A(:,1)<=RangeMax); B = A(idx,:);` to filter out the rows which satisfy your condition. If that's not right, it would be most helpful for you to [edit] your question and replace your code snippet with a [mcve], i.e. create a small example we can test with expected inputs/outputs representative of your true data, so we can run it.

Comment: `A = readmatrix("linelist_H216O.txt");   %Loads H20 Linelist
RangeMin = 2045;                        %Minimum Wavenumber
RangeMax = 2155;                        %Maximum Wavenumber
MinInd = find(A(:,1)>RangeMin,1);       %Index of Min WN
MaxInd = find(A(:,1)>=RangeMax,1);      %Index of Max WN
B = A(MinInd:MaxInd, [1, 5]);           %Column 1 and 5 of A (WN and Linestrengths (S)) within range
C = [1:25]';                            %Numbers
[L,I] = maxk(B(:,2), 25, 1);            %Get indices of 20 highest S
E = [C, B(I,:)];                        %WN and respective S in order`

Comment: Managed to fix it in a completely different way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
A = readmatrix("linelist_H216O.txt");   %Loads H20 Linelist
RangeMin = 2045;                        %Minimum Wavenumber
RangeMax = 2155;                        %Maximum Wavenumber
MinInd = find(A(:,1)>RangeMin,1);       %Index of Min WN
MaxInd = find(A(:,1)>=RangeMax,1);      %Index of Max WN
B = A(MinInd:MaxInd, [1, 5]);           %Column 1 and 5 of A (WN and Linestrengths (S)) within range
C = [1:25]';                            %Numbers
[L,I] = maxk(B(:,2), 25, 1);            %Get indices of 25 highest S
E = [C, B(I,:)];                        %WN and respective S in order
```